# Deploy a local testnet

Tags: plutus, stake-pool, testnet

To test plutus scripts and transactions, I want to have a lightweight environment which I can use when I have no internet. So, how can I deploy a local testnet in the Babbage era for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local testnet can easily be deployed in the babbage era via the following script in the node repository [(1)](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/scripts/babbage/mkfiles.sh). This method requires you to quickly sequence some commands. This is due to [this](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/edbef89ddced36b622423bed25281d12b0c116b7/scripts/babbage/mkfiles.sh#L38) and failing to launch the stake pools within the 30 seconds will result in not correctly deploying the testnet. I think you can change the 30 `start_time` yourself to overcome this. The scripts also assumes that the `cardano-node` and `cardano-cli` binaries are in your path. Personally, I just enter a nix-shell in the node repository to have these available.

To use this script, you must run it from the `cardano-node/` directory via the command

```
./scripts/babbage/mkfiles.sh
```

This will create the directory `cardano-node/example`. In this folder, there are three other scripts that each deploy a stake pool for the testnet (`node-spo*.sh`). These need to be deployed before the `start_time` (30 seconds from the `mkfiles.sh` script execution), so it is good practice to have 3 terminals ready. These `node-spo*.sh` scripts also need to be executed from the `cardano-node/` directory, not the `cardano-node/example/` directory. This is because there are some file structures hard-coded in the scripts. To launch the first stake pool, execute the command,

```
./example/node-spo1.sh
```

Do the same for `node-spo2.sh` and `node-spo3.sh`. The testnet is now running!

The example folder contains the following files. Most notably, you have geneses UTxO keys in the `example/utxo-keys/` folder, where the address can be derived via the command,

```
cardano-cli genesis initial-addr --verification-key-file utxo-keys/utxo1.vkey --testnet-magic 42
```

```
.
├── byron-gen-command
│   ├── genesis-keys.000.key
│   ├── genesis-keys.001.key
│   └── genesis-keys.002.key
├── byron.genesis.spec.json
├── configuration.yaml
├── delegate-keys
│   ├── delegate1.counter
│   ├── delegate1.kes.skey
│   ├── delegate1.kes.vkey
│   ├── delegate1.skey
│   ├── delegate1.vkey
│   ├── delegate1.vrf.skey
│   ├── delegate1.vrf.vkey
│   ├── delegate2.counter
│   ├── delegate2.kes.skey
│   ├── delegate2.kes.vkey
│   ├── delegate2.skey
│   ├── delegate2.vkey
│   ├── delegate2.vrf.skey
│   ├── delegate2.vrf.vkey
│   ├── delegate3.counter
│   ├── delegate3.kes.skey
│   ├── delegate3.kes.vkey
│   ├── delegate3.skey
│   ├── delegate3.vkey
│   ├── delegate3.vrf.skey
│   ├── delegate3.vrf.vkey
│   ├── opcert1.cert
│   ├── opcert2.cert
│   └── opcert3.cert
├── genesis
│   ├── byron
│   │   └── genesis.json
│   └── shelley
│       ├── genesis.alonzo.json
│       └── genesis.json
├── genesis.alonzo.spec.json
├── genesis-keys
│   ├── genesis1.skey
│   ├── genesis1.vkey
│   ├── genesis2.skey
│   ├── genesis2.vkey
│   ├── genesis3.skey
│   └── genesis3.vkey
├── genesis.spec.json
├── main.sock -> node-spo1/node.sock
├── node-spo1
│   ├── byron-delegate.key
│   ├── byron-delegation.cert
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── immutable
│   │   │   ├── 00000.chunk
│   │   │   ├── 00000.primary
│   │   │   └── 00000.secondary
│   │   ├── ledger
│   │   ├── lock
│   │   ├── protocolMagicId
│   │   └── volatile
│   │       └── blocks-0.dat
│   ├── kes.skey
│   ├── node.log
│   ├── node.sock
│   ├── opcert.cert
│   ├── port
│   ├── topology.json
│   └── vrf.skey
├── node-spo1.sh
├── node-spo2
│   ├── byron-delegate.key
│   ├── byron-delegation.cert
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── immutable
│   │   │   ├── 00000.chunk
│   │   │   ├── 00000.primary
│   │   │   └── 00000.secondary
│   │   ├── ledger
│   │   ├── lock
│   │   ├── protocolMagicId
│   │   └── volatile
│   │       └── blocks-0.dat
│   ├── kes.skey
│   ├── node.log
│   ├── node.sock
│   ├── opcert.cert
│   ├── port
│   ├── topology.json
│   └── vrf.skey
├── node-spo2.sh
├── node-spo3
│   ├── byron-delegate.key
│   ├── byron-delegation.cert
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── immutable
│   │   │   ├── 00000.chunk
│   │   │   ├── 00000.primary
│   │   │   └── 00000.secondary
│   │   ├── ledger
│   │   ├── lock
│   │   ├── protocolMagicId
│   │   └── volatile
│   │       └── blocks-0.dat
│   ├── kes.skey
│   ├── node.log
│   ├── node.sock
│   ├── opcert.cert
│   ├── port
│   ├── topology.json
│   └── vrf.skey
├── node-spo3.sh
├── pools
│   ├── cold1.skey
│   ├── cold1.vkey
│   ├── cold2.skey
│   ├── cold2.vkey
│   ├── cold3.skey
│   ├── cold3.vkey
│   ├── kes1.vkey
│   ├── kes2.vkey
│   ├── kes3.vkey
│   ├── opcert1.counter
│   ├── opcert2.counter
│   ├── opcert3.counter
│   ├── staking-reward1.skey
│   ├── staking-reward1.vkey
│   ├── staking-reward2.skey
│   ├── staking-reward2.vkey
│   ├── staking-reward3.skey
│   ├── staking-reward3.vkey
│   ├── vrf1.vkey
│   ├── vrf2.vkey
│   └── vrf3.vkey
├── run
│   └── all.sh
├── stake-delegator-keys
│   ├── payment1.skey
│   ├── payment1.vkey
│   ├── payment2.skey
│   ├── payment2.vkey
│   ├── payment3.skey
│   ├── payment3.vkey
│   ├── staking1.skey
│   ├── staking1.vkey
│   ├── staking2.skey
│   ├── staking2.vkey
│   ├── staking3.skey
│   └── staking3.vkey
└── utxo-keys
    ├── utxo1.skey
    ├── utxo1.vkey
    ├── utxo2.skey
    ├── utxo2.vkey
    ├── utxo3.skey
    └── utxo3.vkey
```

---

**EDIT:** Recently the `example/run/all.sh` has been added to the repo, this lets you run all three `example/node-spo*.sh` all at once.