# Devnet for Cardano

Tags: cardano-node, devnet

Is there a Devnet(single node) available for Cardano?. With other blockchains you can get instruction abt configuring Devnet, Testnet and Mainnet. With Cardano I read only about Testnet and Mainnet. Can you please let me know if devnet configuration is available?.

Answer (score 2):

Running a local single-node cardano devnet is actually quite simple. But I also do not remember seeing any documentation about it.

Maybe this docker-compose.yaml from the Hydra demo and the configuration used in there will help you get started: https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc/blob/cc8f40fcd21261329ca36a3f7c03981721977631/demo/docker-compose.yaml#L4-L22

The hydra demo starts a single cardano-node given some fixed credentials, which starts in the wanted Era right away and produces blocks as the single stake pool on the network. Make sure to also check out the [prepare-devnet.sh](https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc/blob/cc8f40fcd21261329ca36a3f7c03981721977631/demo/prepare-devnet.sh) script, which needs to be executed before starting the docker container (it sets start times of the devnet, which need to be recent enough)

Comment: I had this question some time ago as well. In the node repo there is also a script that starts a local testnet. See https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/deploy-a-local-testnet

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html) you can find the different environments available with Cardano.

Documentation on how to configure them could be incomplete due to the fact that new testnets where created recently.

You can also find additional information on the [developer portal](https://developers.cardano.org/)